# Javascript Charting Package Capable of Producing Chart Shown

Tags: javascript, charts

[image: Box Plot]

Are there and Javascript charting packages that would enable me to create the chart shown?

- Box plots (red) with median
- Normal population range (green)
- Value under test (red diamond)

To put this in context, these are marker measurements for a given condition.  The green box represents the range of readings for the population without the condition (normal/reference population).  The box plot represents the readings for people with the condition (true positives).  The red diamond represents the reading for a person being tested for the condition.

Answer (score 1):

you can try http://g.raphaeljs.com/ which excellent lib for the javacript charting capability.